# How to crop XFile image if i have the coordinate that should be cropped (right,top,left,bottom)?

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit, imagepicker, image-cropper

I'm using google-mlkit-object-detection where the detector detects for me many objects in an image and return for me RECT with the coordinate that detects so how can i crop these. ? as image